# Retrieve value that is stored in db and display in select box using angularjs and laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am trying to retrieve a value that was stored in my MySQL database and display the selected value from the database along with the other select box items so that they can be updated. **The problem that I am having is that the select box is not displaying the selected value that is stored in the database**, instead it defaults to the empty first option. I am using angularjs to retrieve the values from laravel:

**laravel**

```
public function getEmployeeshifts() {
    $employeeShift = DB::table('shift')
                       ->select('shiftId', 'title')
                       ->get();

    return Response::json($employeeShift);
}
```

**angularjs**

```
$http.get('/schedule/employeeshifts').success(function(shiftdata) {
    $scope.employeeshifts = shiftdata;
});
```

---

**html**

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" name="employeeshift"
                                      ng-model="time.employeeshift"
                                      ng-init="time.employeeshift='{{$schedules[0]->title}}'" 
                                      ng-options="employeeshift.title for employeeshift in employeeshifts track by employeeshift.shiftId" required>
        <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

**desired output**

```
<option value="101">Shift A</option>
<option value="102">Shift B</option>
<option value="103">Shift C</option>
```

Based on the above *desired output* what i actually want to store in the database is the value but I need to show the words to the user. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, therefore I am asking for assistance to this problem.

Comment: This question is vague, and I am having a hard time figuring what your problem is

Comment: @Patrick. All the items are in the select box but the value that is stored in the db is not being shown as the selected item, instead it only shows the default option as the selected item, ie: "--Select Shift--". Is that more precise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS automatically resolves which item is selected based on the value of `ng-model`. It appears that you are setting the value of `time.employeeshift` to a `title` value and not a `shiftId` value. Try changing your `ng-init` attribute to `time.employeeshift='{{$schedules[0]->id}}'` or it's equivalent.

Comment: If I change from "title" to "id" the select box will then attempt to display the id's to the user, but what I need is the text to be displayed to the user and id remain in the "<option value='101'>" section. @Ben

Comment: The `value` of the `option` is supposed to match the `ng-model` value. The text node of the `option` tag shouldn't be affected.

Comment: I have been trying your way. The browser's console says I have the correct value `ng-init="time.employeeshift=3"` but, on submission, it sends the value that is in the <option value="2"> which doesn't correspond to the ng-init's value. @Ben Harold

Comment: If the value of `time.employeeshift` is updated after your `init` call, for some unknown reason, it will affect the selected option. Try dumping you entire `time` object to the page with something like: `{{ time | json }}` and verify the `time.employeeshift` is really equal to 3 when you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your model to the desired selected item. In your case, you are not setting it correctly in your `ng-init`. You should use employeeshift as your model.

```
<select ng-model="employeeshift"
        ng-init="employeeshift = employeeshifts[0]" 
        ng-options="employeeshift.title for employeeshift in employeeshifts">
        <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```

This will bind the selected shift object to the `$scope.employeeshift` variable, and set the default value to the *first object in your employeeshifts array*.

Comment: I tried it but it did not work. The value options defaulted to <option value="0"></option>, <option value="1"></option> instead of what I needed in the desired output above.  Moreover, the select box was not set to the actual value stored in the table, eg: Shift B.@Patrick